# How to trigger a button in the front-end if user is not loggedIn

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to make that if my user isn't loggedIn and tries to submit a file, my auth in in my utils folder catches it and opens up the login modal but since I can't use document.findElementById in express what would be the best approach for it?

Obs: The login modal is triggered by the login button

> ```
> const withAuth = (req, res, next) => {
> if(!req.session.user_id) {
>     // what should I put here?
> } else {
>     next()
> } }
> ```
>
> module.exports = withAuth;

Comment: If I understand correctly - you are trying to redirect to a specific page if the user is not logged in. Am I correct? If so, you can simply use `res.redirect('/foo/bar')`.
Documentation: 
http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: I'm trying to open my modal that has the login form, the modal isn't attached to any href